# SwiftUI + Scenekit + Combine + GeometryReader ==> Scrollable List of 3D Models + Rotation of 3D Models By Scrolling the List

Tags: scenekit, swiftui, combine

I want to create a scrollable list of 3D models(here: default ship model of Xcode which you can find in a **Game** project of Xcode).

For that I've created 3 *View* structures:

- one for viewing the 3D model (called *ScenekitView*)
- one for a CardView (called *MyCardView*)
- one for the scrollable list of 3D models(called MyCardsListView)

Here are the Structures:

**ScenekitView**
(btw I added the *art.scnassets* folder of Xcode's default *Game* project to my *Single View App* project)

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct ScenekitView : UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var yRotation : Float
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)
        // create and add a light to the scene
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light!.type = .omni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)
        // create and add an ambient light to the scene
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light!.type = .ambient
        ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGray
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)
        // retrieve the ship node
        let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!
        // animate the 3d object
        ship.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: self.yRotation * Float((Double.pi)/180.0) , z: 0)
        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = SCNView()
        return scnView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ scnView: SCNView, context: Context) {
        scnView.scene = scene
        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        scnView.showsStatistics = true
        // configure the view
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ScenekitView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScenekitView(yRotation: .constant(0))
    }
}
#endif
```

**MyCardView**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyCardView : View {
    @Binding var yRotation: Float

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .opacity(0.8)
                    .frame(width:250, height: 70)
                Text( "Ship \( self.yRotation )" )
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
            }
            ScenekitView(yRotation: self.$yRotation )
                .frame(width: 250, height: 250)
        }
        .cornerRadius(35)
        .frame(width: 250,height: 320)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct MyCardView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyCardView(yRotation: .constant(90))
    }
}
#endif
```

**MyCardsListView**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyCardsListView: View {
    @State var yRotation: Float = 0
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0...2) { number in
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        MyCardView(yRotation: self.$yRotation )
                        .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(geometry.frame(in: .global).minX) / -20), axis: (x: 0, y: 10, z: 0))
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 250, height: 350)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct Product3DView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyCardsListView()
    }
}
#endif
```

In *MyCardsListView* I'm getting each Card's minimum X position using `GeometryReader`

**My goal is:**

while I'm scrolling the *Cards* in *MyCardsListView*, every ship model should rotate with respect to **its Card's** minimum X position (all of them shouldn't rotate with same rotation angle at the same time)

(I know I might made lots of mistakes in using Bindings, States and etc, Sorry about that)

Comment: @kontiki   Please check my question again, I've changed it, but you got the idea from the last one (sorry about the edits)

Comment: There are several problems in your code. The two most relevant: 1. You are never assigning a value to yRotation and 2. If every view will have a different rotation, then you need three yRotation variables. But you only have one! I would start by fixing that.

Comment: @kontiki Thanks a lot Kontiki, I appreciate it. I know you got the idea, but this design is approximately what we're going to create: https://dribbble.com/shots/5030547-Chairs-Store-App

Comment: I posted more details in the answer, there are several problems you need to address.

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems in your code:

1. You never assign a value to `yRotation`.
2. You only have one `yRotation` variable in `MyCardsListView`, but because you want to have different rotation values, depending on the view's position, you need one `yRotation` variable for each view.
3. The following line:

```swift
ship.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: self.yRotation * Float((Double.pi)/180.0) , z: 0)
```

is inside the `makeUIView()` method, but that method is only executed once (when your view is created). You want the value to update continously, so you should assign the value in `updateUIView()` instead.

You should definitely watch WWDC sessions **226: Data Flow in SwiftUI** and **231: Integrating SwiftUI**.

Comment: I'll watch them and check my code again. Thanks again, you're very patient, kind, and responsive Kontiki

Comment: Thanks, Find the answer and feel free to post your solution as a tutorial to your awesome blog✌️